# Batch processing from N producers to 1 consumer

Tags: celery, google-bigquery, pipeline, producer-consumer

I have built a distributed (celery based) parser that deal with about **30K files per day**. Each file ([edi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_data_interchange) file) is parsed as JSON and save in a file. The goal is to populate a Big Query dataset.

The generated JSON is Biq Query schema compliant and can be load as is to our dataset (table). **But we are limited by 1000 load jobs per day**. The incoming messages must be load to BQ as fast as possible.

So the target is: for every message, parse it by a celery task, each result will be buffered in a 300 items size (distributed) buffer . When the buffer reach the limit then all data (json data) are aggregated to be pushed into Big Query.

I found [Celery Batch](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/reference/celery.contrib.batches.html) but the need is for a production environment but is the closest solution out of the box that I found.

Note: Rabbitmq is the message broker and the application is shipped with docker.

Thanks,

Comment: What's the question here? You can use streaming inserts and you are not limited, only to 100.000 items / seconds, that's huge. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use streaming inserts, your limit there is 100.000 items / seconds.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery

Comment: That sounds great, I Will make further tests. Thanks !!

Comment: While batch is free, streaming costs... you might want to unify the files prior to upload and use batch in order to save some money.

Comment: Note that streaming allows your just-inserted data to be instantly queried, which will help with the "The incoming messages must be load to BQ as fast as possible" goal. Batch load has high latency variance and none of the data is visible to queries until the entire load job is completed.

Comment: With the following test: watch bq insert dataset.table json_new_line_separeted.json. During about 2 hours, the table info was update after about 1 hour, while data instantly.